# If $V_1,\ldots,V_n$ are proper subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^d$, how large is $\mathbb{R}^d\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that, if $V_1,\ldots,V_n$ are proper subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $\mathbb{R}^d\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i\neq\emptyset$ (for example, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26/can-a-vector-space-over-an-infinite-field-be-a-finite-union-of-proper-subspaces)). My question is whether one can assure that $\mathbb{R}^d\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$ contains an element of $\mathbb{N}^d$.

Motivation: I would need this to fully understand a proof of Gallai theorem in Ramsey theory that I was taught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{R}^d\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i\neq\emptyset$ you can pick an element $x\in\mathbb{R}^d\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$. Then since $x$ has positive distance to each $V_i$ you can find a ball around $x$ not meeting any $V_i$. Then consider scaling up this ball away from the origin by an enormous factor. It still won't meet any of the $V_i$, but if its radius is sufficiently large then it has to contain an integer point.